# Xamarin Forms Carousel View funciona en Android pero no se muestra en iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, carrusel

Estoy haciendo una app en Xamarin Forms, utilizando el nuget Carousel View, estoy probando, y ya me funciona perfecto en Android, ya se muestra el carrusel, pero en ios no se muestra, instalé el Nuget en el proyecto compartido, en el proyecto android y en el proyecto ios, no encuentro solución al problema, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Aquí inicializo el carrusel en la app de ios

```
using CarouselView.FormsPlugin.iOS;

namespace FortiaApp.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            RoundedBoxViewRenderer.Init();
            AnimationViewRenderer.Init();
            CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

y aquí el código del proyecto compartido

```
private View[] _views;

        public frmDetalle(int idUsuario)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
            lblSaludo.Text = utileriasServices.getSaludo();
            lblFecha.Text = utileriasServices.getFecha();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var response = await fortiaServices.PostAsinc<AccountModel>(new Account { IdUser = this.idUsuario }, "/GetInfoInit");
                if (response != null)
                {
                    this.accountModel = response;

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        var responseToken = await fortiaServices.PostAsinc<TokenApiResponse>(new Object(), "/GetToken");

                        if (responseToken != null)
                        {
                            this.accountModel.tokenApi = responseToken;
                            this.accountModel.idTarjeta = this.accountModel.account.idTarjetaPrincipal;

                            //Agrega tarjetas
                            _views = new View[accountModel.Tarjetas.Count + 1];
                            _views[0] = new frmTarjeta(this.accountModel, this.accountModel.idTarjeta);

                            for (var i = 0; i < accountModel.Tarjetas.Count; i++)
                            {
                                this.accountModel.idTarjeta = this.accountModel.Tarjetas[i].IdTarjeta;
                                _views[i + 1] = new frmTarjeta(this.accountModel, this.accountModel.Tarjetas[i].IdTarjeta);
                            }
                            Carousel.ItemsSource = _views;
                            await GetInfoPrincipal();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Tenemos problemas", "Los servicios no estan disponibles", "Continuar");
                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new frmLogin());
                        }
                    });

                    await Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);
                    await DisplayAlert("Tenemos problemas", "Los servicios no estan disponibles", "Continuar");
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new frmLogin());
                }
            });
        }
```

Aquí muestro la salida en las dos plataformas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya encontré solución, cuando se trata de dispositivo iOS, hay que darle una medida "width y height" porque android se ajusta al tamaño de la pantalla, pero en iOS hay que ser específico para cada dispositivo.

Comment: Agrega el código y marca tu respuesta como aceptada, ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio. Gracias :D